# Deadlock on insert/select

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Ok, I'm totally lost on deadlock issue. I just don't know how to solve this.

I have these three tables (I have removed not important columns):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ManageServicesRequest]
(
    [ReferenceTransactionId]    INT                 NOT NULL,
    [OrderDate]                 DATETIMEOFFSET(7)   NOT NULL,
    [QueuePriority]             INT                 NOT NULL,
    [Queued]                    DATETIMEOFFSET(7)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ManageServicesRequest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReferenceTransactionId]),
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServiceChange]
(
    [ReferenceTransactionId]    INT                 NOT NULL,
    [ServiceId]                 VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    [ServiceStatus]             CHAR(1)             NOT NULL,
    [ValidFrom]                 DATETIMEOFFSET(7)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ServiceChange] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReferenceTransactionId],[ServiceId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ServiceChange_ManageServiceRequest] FOREIGN KEY ([ReferenceTransactionId]) REFERENCES [ManageServicesRequest]([ReferenceTransactionId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    INDEX [IDX_ServiceChange_ManageServiceRequestId] ([ReferenceTransactionId]),
    INDEX [IDX_ServiceChange_ServiceId] ([ServiceId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServiceChangeParameter]
(
    [ReferenceTransactionId]    INT                 NOT NULL,
    [ServiceId]                 VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    [ParamCode]                 VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    [ParamValue]                VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    [ParamValidFrom]            DATETIMEOFFSET(7)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ServiceChangeParameter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReferenceTransactionId],[ServiceId],[ParamCode]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ServiceChangeParameter_ServiceChange] FOREIGN KEY ([ReferenceTransactionId],[ServiceId]) REFERENCES [ServiceChange] ([ReferenceTransactionId],[ServiceId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    INDEX [IDX_ServiceChangeParameter_ManageServiceRequestId] ([ReferenceTransactionId]),
    INDEX [IDX_ServiceChangeParameter_ServiceId] ([ServiceId]),
    INDEX [IDX_ServiceChangeParameter_ParamCode] ([ParamCode])
)
```

And these two procedures:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateManageServicesRequest]
    @ReferenceTransactionId INT,
    @OrderDate DATETIMEOFFSET,
    @QueuePriority INT,
    @Services ServiceChangeUdt READONLY,
    @Parameters ServiceChangeParameterUdt READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    /* VYTVOŘ NOVÝ REQUEST NA ZMĚNU SLUŽEB */

        /*  INSERT REQUEST  */
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ManageServicesRequest]
            ([ReferenceTransactionId]
            ,[OrderDate]
            ,[QueuePriority]
            ,[Queued])
        VALUES
            (@ReferenceTransactionId
            ,@OrderDate
            ,@QueuePriority
            ,NULL)

        /*  INSERT SERVICES */
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceChange]
            ([ReferenceTransactionId]
            ,[ServiceId]
            ,[ServiceStatus]
            ,[ValidFrom])
        SELECT 
             @ReferenceTransactionId AS [ReferenceTransactionId]
            ,[ServiceId]
            ,[ServiceStatus]
            ,[ValidFrom]
        FROM @Services AS [S]

        /*  INSERT PARAMS   */
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceChangeParameter]
            ([ReferenceTransactionId]
            ,[ServiceId]
            ,[ParamCode]
            ,[ParamValue]
            ,[ParamValidFrom])
        SELECT 
            @ReferenceTransactionId AS [ReferenceTransactionId]
            ,[ServiceId]
            ,[ParamCode]
            ,[ParamValue]
            ,[ParamValidFrom]
        FROM @Parameters AS [P]

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        THROW
    END CATCH
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetManageServicesRequest]
    @ReferenceTransactionId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY 
        /* VRAŤ MANAGE SERVICES REQUEST PODLE ID */

        SELECT 
            [MR].[ReferenceTransactionId], 
            [MR].[OrderDate], 
            [MR].[QueuePriority], 
            [MR].[Queued], 
            
            [SC].[ReferenceTransactionId], 
            [SC].[ServiceId], 
            [SC].[ServiceStatus], 
            [SC].[ValidFrom],
            
            [SP].[ReferenceTransactionId], 
            [SP].[ServiceId], 
            [SP].[ParamCode], 
            [SP].[ParamValue], 
            [SP].[ParamValidFrom]

        FROM [dbo].[ManageServicesRequest] AS [MR]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ServiceChange] AS [SC] ON [SC].[ReferenceTransactionId] = [MR].[ReferenceTransactionId]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ServiceChangeParameter] AS [SP] ON [SP].[ReferenceTransactionId] = [SC].[ReferenceTransactionId] AND [SP].[ServiceId] = [SC].[ServiceId]
        WHERE [MR].[ReferenceTransactionId] = @ReferenceTransactionId

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        THROW
    END CATCH
END
```

Now these are used this way (it's a simplified C# method that creates a record and then posts record to a micro service queue):

```cs
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreateCommand> context)
{
    using (var sql = sqlFactory.Cip)
    {
        /*SAVE REQUEST TO DATABASE*/
        sql.StartTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable); <----- First transaction starts

        /* Create id */
        var transactionId = await GetNewId(context.Message.CorrelationId);

        /* Create manage services request */
        await sql.OrderingGateway.ManageServices.Create(transactionId,  context.Message.ApiRequest.OrderDate, context.Message.ApiRequest.Priority, services);

        sql.Commit(); <----- First transaction ends
        

        /// .... Some other stuff ...

        /* Fetch the same object you created in the first transaction */
        Try
        {
            sql.StartTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
            
            var request = await sql.OrderingGateway.ManageServices.Get(transactionId); <----- HERE BE THE DEADLOCK, 

            request.Queued = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            await sql.OrderingGateway.ManageServices.Update(request);

            ... Here is a posting to a microservice queue ...
        
            sql.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sql.RollBack();
        }
        
        /// .... Some other stuff ....
}
```

Now my problem is. Why are these two procedures getting deadlocked? The first and the second transaction are never run in parallel for the same record.

Here is the deadlock detail:

```xml
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process1dbfa86c4e8" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process1dbfa86c4e8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057594046775296 (b42d8e559092)" waittime="2503" ownerId="33411557480" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-12-01T01:06:15.303" XDES="0x1ddd2df4420" lockMode="RangeS-S" schedulerid="20" kpid="23000" status="suspended" spid="55" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-01T01:06:15.310" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-01T01:06:15.300" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.300" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostpid="11020" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="33411557480" currentdb="18" currentdbname="xxx" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="xxx.dbo.spGetManageServicesRequest" line="10" stmtstart="356" stmtend="4256" sqlhandle="0x030012001374fc02f91433019aad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"></frame>
      </executionStack>
    </process>
    <process id="process1dbfa1c1c28" taskpriority="0" logused="1232" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057594046971904 (ffffffffffff)" waittime="6275" ownerId="33411563398" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-12-01T01:06:16.450" XDES="0x3d4e842c420" lockMode="RangeI-N" schedulerid="31" kpid="36432" status="suspended" spid="419" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-01T01:06:16.480" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-01T01:06:16.463" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.463" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider"  hostpid="11020" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="33411563398" currentdb="18" currentdbname="xxx" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="xxx.dbo.spCreateManageServicesRequest" line="40" stmtstart="2592" stmtend="3226" sqlhandle="0x03001200f01ab84aeb1433019aad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"></frame>
      </executionStack>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594046775296" dbid="18" objectname="xxx.dbo.ServiceChange" indexname="PK_ServiceChange" id="lock202ecfd0380" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594046775296">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1dbfa1c1c28" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1dbfa86c4e8" mode="RangeS-S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594046971904" dbid="18" objectname="xxx.dbo.ServiceChangeParameter" indexname="PK_ServiceChangeParameter" id="lock27d3d371880" mode="RangeS-S" associatedObjectId="72057594046971904">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1dbfa86c4e8" mode="RangeS-S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1dbfa1c1c28" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Why is this deadlock happening? How do I avoid it in the future?

Edit:
Here is a plan for Get procedure: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1UMMhaqF

Another Edit:
After GSerg comment, I changed the line number in the deadlock graph from 65 to 40, due to removed columns that are not important to the question.

Comment: Deadlocks happen when two (or more) processes try to take out locks on the same group of tables, but in different orders, which leads to the processes waiting on each other to complete - and they can't complete because they're waiting on each other. Have you tried wrapping your multi-table inserts in a transaction yet so that the insert locks are held as a group?

Comment: Yes, before the insert store procedure is called, serializable transaction is started.

Comment: +1 for providing `CREATE TABLE` and indexes, as well as the deadlock graph. Can you also please share the relevant query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Your `spCreateManageServicesRequest` does not have `line="65"`.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I removed some collumns that were not important to make the question shorter(those columns have no constraints and are not computed) that 65 is equal to 40 in the posted script. Deadlock occurs on insert into ServiceChangeParameter

Comment: Notice that according to the deadlock details, `spGetManageServicesRequest` runs before `spCreateManageServicesRequest` (`lastbatchstarted`). `Consume` is `async` - are you sure it only runs one at a time and/or you get the new id in a thread-safe manner? I mean, with Isolation level Serializable "Volatile data can be read but not modified, and no new data can be added during the transaction."

Comment: Instead of the two indices on `ReferenceTransactionId` and `ServiceId`, have one index on `ReferenceTransactionId, ServiceId`.

Comment: Arie: well its a microservice. Those store procedures run in parallel in large numbers. But never for the same ManageServicesRequest item.

Comment: GSerg, do you mean I should remove those two indexes on ServiceChange and just leave the primary key clustered constraint?

Comment: No, I overlooked you have this covered in the primary key.

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't see the need for transactions at all. Of course you may have skipped some steps here, which may change picture.

Comment: Arvo: The transaction is needed mostly before posting to a microservice queue. I update the record with a new date (set queued value) and post it. Now there is alot of stuff that can go wrong and I need to rollback in case that que does not accept the message for any reason. I also need to lock the record during posting. Because another service that actually processes the created records from that queue is looking for created records without the queued date.

Comment: Does your getNewId() access database?

Comment: Yes it does, it creates a record in another unreleated table to deadlock. Should I add it to the question?

Comment: Unless `spGetManageServicesRequest` is running in a transaction with other operations before it, the deadlock graph doesn't seem to square with the query plan. The graph shows `ServiceChangeParameter` already had a `RangeS-S` lock *before* a lock was attempted on `ServiceChange`. Whereas in the query plan, `ServiceChange` was accesses first (and there are only locks on the clustered indexes involved here so it must be in that order).

Comment: As a side point, I feel the actual C# code is inefficient: you shouldn't need to retrieve the object you just created, let the `INSERT` code pass it back, perhaps using an `OUTPUT` clause. And I feel you are holding locks for too long. Locks should really only be held for a very short time. If you need to track whether something was posted correctly, you should assign it a `PostAttempted` then `Posted` status, or something like that

Comment: Charlieface, that consume code is a microservice code. There are parallel requests to this service. Right now its a 50 requests a second. The problem is the deadlock occurs on unrelated items. For example, there are 2 requests to create CreateManageServicesRequest. So "Consume" is called in parallel. But one of those randomly fails on deadlock even tho the requests are not related in any way, as if one of those is locking more than it needs.

Comment: About getNewId() - does it READ anything from tables in question? If yes, then deadlock reason is clear :)

Comment: Arvo: No it inserts a record and return id on output parameter

Comment: Indeed, `SERIALIZABLE` takes a `RangeS-S` lock, which can be quite wide. But the main issue is that it's locking in the wrong order: it should be locking `ServiceChange` before locking `ServiceChangeParameter`, and according to the query plan that is what it does. So either you have a different query plan being executed, or there is something else in between `StartTransaction` and `Get`.

Comment: Charlieface: there is nothing else between the start transaction and getting statement. I just ran the procedure again to see the query plan and its like I've sent it. I don't know why is the order different in the deadlock graph.

Comment: Is there perhaps an outer transaction around the whole thing? As `COMMIT` will not commit anything until the last transaction is committed

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Well, second pair of operations then: ManageServices.Get locks resources for READ, Manageservices.Update for UPDATE and this is prone to deadlock (if any resources overlap).

Comment: Arvo: the update statement doesnt get executed. It fails on the get statement. Code tries to retrieve the created record but cannot. The graph then shows it deadlocked with create procedure, but the create procedure is called for completely unrelated record.

Comment: Well, I can't follow all those plans just now :( General guidelines (how I have solved deadlock problems): a) use transactions inside single procedure (this way you have better control over sql behavior); b) use updlock hints in select statements to change resource lock types; c) use rowlock hints to limit deadlock situations (does not help for some key locks); d) handle deadlocks properly - retry few times and/or fail 'meaningfully' :)

Comment: `ROWLOCK` can be useful in some situations, you could try it but I doubt it will help much for a range lock. What about adding `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` to the `Get` query

Comment: You can have deadlock / race condition problems when the same column / set of columns is included in more than 1 index. I notice that you have `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReferenceTransactionId]` and `INDEX [IDX_ServiceChangeParameter_ManageServiceRequestId] ([ReferenceTransactionId]),`. I suggest you get rid of the `IDX_ServiceChangeParameter_ManageServiceRequestId` as it is redundant and can cause problems when different queries use different indexes to find the same set of records.

Comment: This may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314886/sql-server-deadlock-caused-by-range-locks-in-index

Comment: Have you considered using `SNAPSHOT` isolation for the `spGetManageServicesRequest` procedure?

Comment: Please **give the definition** of ServiceChangeUdt and ServiceChangeParameterUdt

Comment: @Charlieface - If you experiment with trace flag 1200 you'll see this order is usual. It first gets an `S` lock on the row in `ManageServicesRequest` then a `RangeS-S` lock on a key in  `ServiceChange` then `RangeS-S` lock on key(s) in `ServiceChangeParameter` but it still has to call GetRow again on  `ServiceChange`  to see if there are any more rows to come from that operator. And in the case that there aren't it will lock a range sufficient to prevent any new matching ones being inserted.

Comment: "Those store procedures run in parallel in large numbers." - that hints that using serializable would not be the right design.....

Comment: @MartinSmith Interesting, you're probably right, I always assumed it would lock the whole range to start with (as it has a single `ReferenceTransactionId` to lock), rather than pulling in the rows and locking one-by-one. I wonder if adding a redundant `AND SP.ReferenceTransactionId = @ReferenceTransactionId` would help

Comment: @Charlieface The range lock locks the range between specific adjacent index keys not a range of values so this will always be row by row. There are composite indexes in both SC and SP so there could be multiple keys with that value and they are just locked when read.The actual range that ends up locked depends on what keys exist in the index (including ghost records) and may lock a considerably larger range of values than specified if the gap between adjacent keys is large (or even the range of values from the end key to infinity as here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are better off avoiding serializable isolation level. The way the serializable guarantee is provided is often deadlock prone.

If you can't alter your stored procs to use more targeted locking hints that guarantee the results you require at a lesser isolation level then you can prevent this particular deadlock scenario shown by ensuring that all locks are taken out on `ServiceChange` first before any are taken out on `ServiceChangeParameter`.

One way of doing this would be to introduce a table variable in `spGetManageServicesRequest` and materialize the results of

```
SELECT ...
FROM [dbo].[ManageServicesRequest] AS [MR]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ServiceChange] AS [SC]  ON [SC].[ReferenceTransactionId] = [MR].[ReferenceTransactionId]
```

to the table variable.

Then join that against `[dbo].[ServiceChangeParameter]` to get your final results.

The phase separation introduced by the table variable will ensure the `SELECT` statement acquires the locks in the same object order as the insert is doing so prevent deadlocks where the `SELECT` statement already holds a lock on `ServiceChangeParameter` and is waiting to acquire one on `ServiceChange` (as in the deadlock graph here).

It may be instructive to look at the exact locks taken out by the `SELECT` running at serializable isolation level. These can be seen with extended events or undocumented trace flag 1200.

Currently your execution plan is below.

[image]

For the following example data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ManageServicesRequest] 
VALUES (26410821, GETDATE(), 1, GETDATE()), 
       (26410822, GETDATE(), 1, GETDATE()), 
       (26410823, GETDATE(), 1, GETDATE());

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceChange] 
VALUES (26410821, 'X', 'X', GETDATE()), 
       (26410822, 'X', 'X', GETDATE()), 
       (26410823, 'X', 'X', GETDATE());

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceChangeParameter]  
VALUES (26410821, 'X', 'P1','P1', GETDATE()), 
       (26410823, 'X', 'P1','P1', GETDATE());
```

The trace flag output (for `WHERE [MR].[ReferenceTransactionId] = 26410822`) is

```
Process 51 acquiring IS lock on OBJECT: 7:1557580587:0  (class bit2000000 ref1) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring IS lock on OBJECT: 7:1509580416:0  (class bit2000000 ref1) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring IS lock on OBJECT: 7:1477580302:0  (class bit2000000 ref1) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 7:1:600  (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring S lock on KEY: 7:72057594044940288 (1b148afa48fb) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 7:1:608  (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring RangeS-S lock on KEY: 7:72057594045005824 (a69d56b089b6) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 7:1:632  (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring RangeS-S lock on KEY: 7:72057594045202432 (c37d1982c3c9) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 51 acquiring RangeS-S lock on KEY: 7:72057594045005824 (2ef5265f2b42) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK
```

The order of locks taken is indicated in the image below. Range locks apply to the range of possible values from the given key value, to the nearest key value below it (in key order - so above it in the image!).

[image]

First node 1 is called and it takes an `S` lock on the row in `ManageServicesRequest`, then node 2 is called and a `RangeS-S` lock is taken on a key in `ServiceChange` the values from this row are then used to do the lookup in `ServiceChangeParameter` - in this case there are no matching rows for the predicate but a `RangeS-S` lock is still taken out covering the range from the next highest key to the preceding one (range `(26410821, 'X', 'P1') ... (26410823, 'X', 'P1')` in this case).

Then node 2 is called again to see if there are any more rows. Even in the case that there aren't an additional `RangeS-S` lock is taken on the next row in `ServiceChange`.

In the case of your deadlock graph it seems that the range being locked in `ServiceChangeParameter` is the range to infinity (denoted by `ffffffffffff`) - this will happen here when it does a look up for a key value at or beyond the last key in the index.

An alternative to the table variable might also be to change the query as below.

```
SELECT ...
FROM [dbo].[ManageServicesRequest] AS [MR]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ServiceChange] AS [SC]  ON [SC].[ReferenceTransactionId] = [MR].[ReferenceTransactionId]
  LEFT HASH JOIN [dbo].[ServiceChangeParameter] AS [SP] ON [SP].[ReferenceTransactionId] = [MR].[ReferenceTransactionId] AND [SP].[ServiceId] = [SC].[ServiceId]
  WHERE [MR].[ReferenceTransactionId] = @ReferenceTransactionId
```

The final predicate on [dbo].[ServiceChangeParameter] is changed to reference `[MR].[ReferenceTransactionId]` instead of `[SC].[ReferenceTransactionId]` and an explicit hash join hint is added.

This gives a plan like the below where all the locks on `ServiceChange` are taken during the hash table build stage before any are taken on `ServiceChangeParameter` - without changing the `ReferenceTransactionId` condition the new plan had a scan rather than a seek on `ServiceChangeParameter` which is why that change was made (it allows the optimiser to use the implied equality predicate on @ReferenceTransactionId)

[image]